# Error: 'glmnet_softmax' is not an exported object from 'namespace:glmnet'

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to use this tutorial https://github.com/wvictor14/planet#infer-ethnicity and get the following error message, even when using the test data provided:

```
pl_infer_ethnicity(pl_betas)
[1] "1860 of 1860 predictors present."
Loading required package: Matrix
Error: 'glmnet_softmax' is not an exported object from 'namespace:glmnet'
```

I've tried re-installing individual packages and running in a new version or R and get the same error.  I believe this is related to other errors posted with a recent update in glmnet. Any tips on how to resolve?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-18 planet_0.1.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lattice_0.20-38  codetools_0.2-16 glmnet_3.0-2     foreach_1.4.7   
 [5] crayon_1.3.4     grid_3.6.2       magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.4.2    
 [9] rlang_0.4.2      remotes_2.1.0    iterators_1.0.12 tools_3.6.2     
[13] compiler_3.6.2   pkgconfig_2.0.3  shape_1.4.4      tibble_2.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it would have worked in the first place; the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/news/news.html) for `glmnet` doesn't say anything one way or the other about `glmnet_softmax` (e.g., it does *not* say "`glmnet_softmax` is no longer exported" or anything like that ...)

In any case, this is a *non-exported* function from the `glmnet` package. It is referred to [here](https://github.com/wvictor14/planet/blob/75e3e87e16a9697c41a03e0aa40cb0d2f9db4a17/R/pl_infer_ethnicity.R#L73) in the tutorial code.

If you can change that line of code to refer to `glmnet:::glmnet_softmax` (i.e., three colons rather than two), that should suffice (`:::` allows you to access a non-exported function).